# Failed to get a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following problem when wanting to get the cell of a table where a change event is not achieving its procurement.

Any idea how to get it , it would be well received .

```
<tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td><div class="switch switch-small">
            <input name="op1" type="checkbox" checked />
          </td></div>
      </td></tr>

$("tbody tr td input:checkbox").change(function() {
    id = $(this).parent().parent().children().index(this.parentNode);
    alert(id);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the HTML please? Thanks!

Comment: <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td><div class="switch switch-small">
            <input name="op1" type="checkbox" checked />
          </td></div>
      </td></tr>

Answer (score 1):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/morape/2/edit?html,css,js,output)***

You **cannot** close a `</div>` after a  `</td>`.  Also you're closing 3 times a `TD` element. Please review your HTML markup immediately.

If you want to get the TD where you clicked the checkbox:

```
$("td :checkbox").change(function() {
    var TD = $(this).closest("td");
    alert(TD.index()); // or use TD.closest("tr").index(); // to get the TR index
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but I suppose you want to get the index corresponding to a radio input. As @Roko mentioned in his answer, your markup is wrong, it should be in the following form:

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
        <div class="switch switch-small">
            <input name="op1" type="checkbox" checked />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Finally to get index, `1`, when input with name `op1` changes, here's how you do that:

```
$("td input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {
    var trParent = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    var id = $("tr").index(trParent);
    alert(id);
});
```

I hope that helps, or you may consider reviewing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simpler

```
$(function() {
    $("table [type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {
        console.log($(this).parent().prev().html());
    });
});
```

jQuery selector meaning : "anything in the table having `type=checkbox`"

Comment: What I want is to get the position where I run the event of change .

Answer (score 0):

var cell = $(this).closest('td');
var cellIndex = cell[0].cellIndex

var row = cell.closest('tr');
var rowIndex = row[0].rowIndex;

Comment: your code will hang if that JS is opened in a page where there's no table.